# Source controlling Esri Web AppBuilder Widgets and Themes

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, node-js, arcgis-custom-widget

I'm not a JavaScript kind of guy but I'm trying to get ramped up in advance of some retirements of the people that have handled our web mapping applications (but whose savvy to source control ranges from 'not very savvy' to 'completely unaware of its existence').  I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gp0vAVH724)'s instructions for using Yeoman/grunt to put these things under source control, but now my source control system finds over 6000 new files, the vast majority being in the `node_modules` folder (see screen shot below).

Can I configure source control to ignore everything in the `node_modules` folder?  Should I commit those files that are *not* in that folder (or should I limit what's in source control just to the `widgets` and/or `themes` folders)?  Must I re-do this scaffolding process for each widget and/or theme I want to source control, or can I place all widgets & themes inside the respective folders within the framework I just scaffolded?

[image: Screen grab of new files generated by Yeoman]